# Wordpress Author details not displaying on landing page

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress the default behavior is that all posts are displayed on the landing of the domain(myblogsite.com) but the post's displayed don't show the author's name or gravatar. This is only shown if the user selects an individual post(myblogsite.com/date/title). Is there a plugin or fix(or hack) to display the author name and gravatar for posts that are displayed on the landing page?

I've looked at similar questions on Wordpress' forum and the solutions I've tried did not work.

As an example:

Add this after or before `<?php the_content(''); ?>`

```
    <?php if ($lw_post_author == "true" && is_attachment() != TRUE) : ?>
<div class="about_author">
<div class="alignleft"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_id(), '28' );   ?></div>
<div class="alignleft"><h4><?php _e('Author','lightword'); ?>: <a href="<?php the_author_url(); ?> "><?php the_author(); ?></a></h4>
<?php the_author_description(); if(!get_the_author_description()) _e('No description. Please complete your profile.','lightword'); ?></div><div class="clear"></div> </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am using Wordpress 4.4.2

Comment: Of course, so far I've tried this in the index.php page: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-author-in-main-page

Comment: Post that in your question! Do not provide a third party link.

Comment: I'm not a developer that is well versed in php. I was just hoping that there was a simple solution to this before I try custom coding Wordpress to enable author details on the homepage.

Comment: Well, no one can give you a solution without you showing your code!

Comment: Ashish apologies for the lack of information. I have updated my question. Please note that the solutions I've looked at were provided 6 years ago and did not work for me. I have found no recent solutions so I thought I'd publish my question here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103600/discussion-between-jonathan-opperman-and-ashish-ahuja).